# Parsing postgres datetime with timezone with optional microseconds

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime, date-formatting

I want to parse postgres datetime with timezone by [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). But I don't know, how to compose `$format` parameter.

```
$dates = [
    '2016-03-04 10:29:40+01',
    '2016-03-04 10:29:40.123456+01',
];

$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.uP';

foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $value);
    var_dump($dt);
}
```

> ```
> bool(false)
>
> object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
>   ["date"]=>
>   string(26) "2016-03-04 10:29:40.123456"
>   ["timezone_type"]=>
>   int(1)
>   ["timezone"]=>
>   string(6) "+01:00"
> }
> ```

First date is not parsed, second yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

As you want `DateTime::createFromFormat()` solution only, you'll face a problem: `createFromFormat()` don't support optional part. There is no way to parse directly a string that *may* have microsecond.

One of the hack you can do is searching for the `.` that's used for the `ms` part, and change your pattern on the fly:

```
<?
$dates = [
    '2016-03-04 10:29:40+01',
    '2016-03-04 10:29:40.123456+01',
];

foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $format = (strpos($value,'.')===FALSE) ?'Y-m-d H:i:sP':'Y-m-d H:i:s.uP';
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $value);
    var_dump($dt);
}
```

---

[PHP::strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php) is probably the best solution if you can't format your output with [Postgresql::to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
<?
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.uP', strtotime('2016-03-04 10:29:40+01'));
// 2016-03-04 01:29:40.000000-08:00

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.uP', strtotime('2016-03-04 10:29:40.123456+01'));
// 2016-03-04 01:29:40.000000-08:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this solution, but I need the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` way

Comment: @venca updated, even if the solution is a bit ugly... can't you use the `Postgresql::to_char()` to drop the `ms` part directly with postgresql ?

Comment: I use on many places in code `Zend\Hydrator\Strategy\DateTimeFormatterStrategy` so the easiest solution is to find correct `$format`. I tried special chars such as `?` without success and I am not sure if there is no way to create format with optional part.

Comment: @venca Ok, I may not be clear: **there is NO correct format that'll allow you to hydrate with and without `ms`**. Either you drop them on the database side, or you hack the way you hydrate them. `'Y-m-d H:i:s+'` is the closest you can go and it'll drop your time zone, far from perfect...